# Acces int from any Activity

Tags: java, android, int

Ok so I'm creating an app which has lots of activities (I'm very new to programming). I want to create an int that is accesible and editable by all activities.

So lets say the int is "points" and it is set to 0 in Activity 1. Then in Activity 2 I access points which is 0 and I set it to 3. After that, in Activity 3 I get points, which now equals 3, and set it to 2. After all that I go back to Activity 1 and get points which now equals 2.

How would i achieve this. I've done some research but from what I've seen I could use intents, ActivityResult, SharedPreferences, Singleton... I just don't know which is best.

Comment: you can pass the value of that int through intent among activities and store it in anyother int and you can use it as you want, why to use only one int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create this in your MainActivity

```
public static int globalInteger;
```

and get it by:

```
MainActivity.globalInteger
```

Answer (score 2):

Both the singleton approach and the shared preferences one proposed by Sarah and colens will fix your need.

Now it depends how long will the scope of those variables will be. If you don't care what happens when your application is close you could use a singleton class. If otherwise you need to be persistent when your app is closed then you need to some storage mechanism as shared preferences.

PD: of course you can mix both techniques and even try others (activity result could work as well) but based on the amount of info given choosing one of above discussed should do it.

Comment: Thank you! And what about the other suggestion, using a public static int. Why would that not work?

Comment: No, that would work aswell (again the limitation that is lost when your app is closed unless you store it) as i said the are numerous ways to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

You should use **Shared Preferences**.
When you want to save your **int** in one of your activites do like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("preference_file_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("your_key", yourInt);
editor.commit();
```

Then to retrieve it from another activity:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("preference_file_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int yourInt=sharedPref.getInt("your_key", defaultValue);
```

**preference_file_key** is a name you use across your activities to access the shared preference object which stores your values.
**your_key** is a string that you use as a key value for the integer you save and retrieve, and **defaultValue** is a value **yourInt** will get if the specified key is not present.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a **Singleton** class. A singleton class is a class that only one Object of it is created. You need to put your primitive (`int points`) in this Singleton class. and in your main class get an instance of this Singleton, whenever you want to use that again, you'll get the previous object that is already created before, so you can use that "point" variable as you want.

> The Singleton's purpose is to control object creation, limiting the
>   number of objects to only one. Since there is only one Singleton
>   instance, any instance fields of a Singleton will occur only once per
>   class, just like static fields.

I recommend reading this article: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm

*There might be other ways to solve this issue too.*